# How to get specific data from a line read using OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c++, .net, string, c++-cli, openfiledialog

Example .txt:

```
127.0.0.1@user1;pass1
127.5.452.211@user2;pass2
27.33.5.31@user3;pass3
127.66.3.32@user4;pass4
```

My program needs to read every single line from my .txt file and after that, to use the IP,username and password its provided there. I only managed to make it read all the lines but i don't know how to select the IP/user/pass from each line for later usage.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             //bool found = true;

             //std::string IP;
             //std::string Username;
             //std::string Password;


             //Stream^ myStream;  
             OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;  
             openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = "c:\\";  
             openFileDialog1->Title = "Game Account Database";  
             openFileDialog1->Filter = "CP files (*.cp)|*.cp|All files (*.*)|*.*|txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";  
             openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;  
             openFileDialog1->Multiselect = true;  

             if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )  
             {  
                 array<String^>^ lines = System::IO::File::ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1->FileName);  
                 for each (String^ line in lines) {  

                     System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("",line);  

                 }  
             }  
         }
};
```

Comment: Did you check that `ReadAllLines` succeed? `openFileDialog1->FileName` may not be giving what you expect.

Comment: It works for me. It shows the lines i have in my .txt file. Why wouldn't it show them ? Please explain so i won't encounter any bugs later on.

Comment: What problem are you actually having here? You said both "It shows the lines" and "Why wouldn't it show them?". Are you trying to read the line of text, or are you trying to read the username & password fields within the line?

Comment: What i want is to extract ip username and password from each line for later usage. About my "Why wouldn't it show them?" question, it was about what Ajay said regarding the ReadAllLines. I didnt understand either. Why wouldnt openFileDialog1->Filename work ?

Comment: They're just trying to figure out what your actual _question_ is. As-is, it appears to be "please write some code for me."

Comment: Well...yes because i tried so many times and couldn't solve it myself. i tried even after i made this post and still nothing.